# Regular Expressions Bug with Javascript/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I have 3 regular expressions here. USERNAME_REGEX & EMAIL_REGEX work independently without any errors. However when I use IDENTITY_REGEX it gives me an invalid character class error:

**REGEX**

```
export const USERNAME_REGEX = "[A-Za-z0-9]{3,16}"
export const EMAIL_REGEX = "[\w\.-]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}"
export const IDENTITY_REGEX = "[A-Za-z0-9]{3,16}|[\w\.-]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}"
```

**Usage Component**

```
  const inputs = [
    {
      id: "identity",
      name: "identity",
      type: "text",
      errorMessage:
        "Username should be 3-16 characters, no special characters allowed",
      label: "Email Address / Username",
      pattern: IDENTITY_REGEX,
      required: true
    },

.....

<FormInput
  key={input.id}
  {...input}
  onChange={onChange}
/>
```

**ERROR**

Pattern attribute value [A-Za-z0-9]{3,16}|[w.-]+@([w-]+.)+[w-]{2,4} is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[A-Za-z0-9]{3,16}|[w.-]+@([w-]+.)+[w-]{2,4}/v: Invalid character in character class

I appreciate your time in advance!

Tried new RegExp() but to no avail

Comment: nope, error not happening - suggest you re-type it (not copy paste) see if the error goes away - oh, wait, didn't see the `/v` - you have to escape the `-`

Comment: I tried changing it to this:

export const IDENTITY_REGEX = "[A-Za-z0-9]{3,16}|[\w\.\-]+@([\w\-]+\.)+[\w\-]{2,4}"

But still got the same error

Comment: in a string representation of a RegExp, if you want \ it needs to be \\ .. `"[A-Za-z0-9]{3,16}|[\\w\\.\\-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[\\w\\-]{2,4}"` - by the way, I think your EMAIL_REGEX is flawed anyway, but there's plenty of email regex's to find on the internet

Comment: Yes! And the reason why I wasnt seeing the error (I think) is because the email inputs default type="email" validation took over?

How do I put your comment as a correct answer haha? Thanks!

Yeah tbf I thought they might be, just an initial implementation ;)

Comment: I wont post an answer as I believe the solution is trivial